# Asking children Psukim in Tanach

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends, talmudic

I remember that chazal used to ask chidren what Pasuk the child is currently learning to know answers to certain questions. Does anybody have a source ?

Answer (score 6):

This occurs a number of times in the Talmud, including [Chagigah 15a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.15a.13?lang=bi) and [Gittin 68a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.68a.3?lang=bi).